# Generating classes using multiple xsd schema with duplicate class entry

Tags: java, maven, xsd, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have multiple xsd schema file which contains multiple/common duplicate xs:element / class entry. I tried them converting into classes using following lines in pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd/schema1</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>schema1.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <packageName>com.schema1.rest.stub</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd/schema2</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>schema2.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <packageName>com.schema2.rest.stub</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

While running with only one `execution` tag I am getting classes successfully. But when I include two or more than two schema or `execution` tag, I am able see only the classes created for last schema "schema2" and not for "schema1".

While running in the command line logs, I can see the classes are getting generated for both of the schema. But the resultant is deleting the older package and recreating it. Basically I am having only classes for the last schema only and not for other schemas.

How I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>` in both `<configuration>` tag.

eg:

```
<configuration>
    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd/schema2</schemaDirectory>
    <schemaIncludes>
        <include>schema2.xsd</include>
    </schemaIncludes>
    <packageName>com.schema2.rest.stub</packageName>
</configuration>
```